# Remote shared folder for XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Is there a solution that will allow my partner and I work on the same files remotely and using XAMPP? There will be not in the same network.

If yes, how do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting up a network connection, between both parties. You can use LAN, or WLAN.

Comment: Can you be more specific or can you provide me a guide from an external source please?

Comment: As I updated my question there will be not in the same network

Comment: @asotshia What do you mean by "there will be not in the same network", I don't understand?

Comment: Through Internet, different locations

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading [hamachi](http://hamachi.en.softonic.com/) and setting up a virtual network that way. Downside to this is that it is only available as long as the "server" machine is connected. I have not tried using XAMPP in this environment, but it should work.

Not the desired solution, but you could also use a file repository site like [basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) to upload files you are working on and each of you install XAMPP separately. Not ideal because it would not be updated in real time, but beyond these two solutions, I don't believe it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure your PHP IDE to use FTP and the remote server. Everything else is handled by the IDE and it's like working on your localhost.